# How to locate a virtualenv install

Tags: python, django

Deploying to a live server for an existing Django application. It's a very old site that has not been updated in 3+ years.

I was hired on contract to bring it up to date, which included upgrading the Django version to be current. This broke many things on the site that had to be repaired.

I did a test deployment and it went fine. Now it is time for deployment to live and I am having some issues....

First thing I was going to do is keep a log of the current Django version on server, incase of any issues we can roll back. I tried logging in Python command prompt and importing Django to find version number, and it said Django not found.

I was looking further and found the version in a pip requirements.txt file.

Then I decided to update the actual django version on the server. Update went through smoothly. Then I checked the live site, and everything was unchanged (with the old files still in place). Most of the site should have been broken. It was not recognizing any changes in Django.

I am assuming the reason for this might be that the last contractor used virtualenv? And that's why it is not recognizing Django, or the Django update are not doing anything to the live site?

That is the only reason I could come up with to explain this issue, as since there is a pip requirements.txt file, he likely installed Django with pip, which means Python should recognize the path to Django.

So then I was going to try to find the source path for the virtualenv with command "lsvirtualenv". But when I do that, even that gives me a "command not found" error.

My only guess is that this was an older version of virtualenv that does not have this command? If that is not the case, I'm not sure what is going on.

Any advice for how I find the information I need to  update the package versions on this server with the tools I have access to?

Comment: _I am assuming the reason for this might be that the last contractor used virtualenv_ why are you guessing about this?  Find out!

Comment: why not start from scratch?

Comment: Typically there would be nginx or apache doing a reverse proxy to gunicorn or other WSGI application server.  If you can look at the configuration of the reverse proxy, it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question title, as this has more to do with locating the virtualenv than updating Django itself

Comment: Maybe you could look for `bin/activate` files? As in: `locate bin/activate`

Answer (score 2):

### Create your own virtualenv

If all fails, just recreate the `virtualenv` from the `requirements.txt` and go from there

### Find out how the old app was being launched

If you insist on finding the old one, IMO the most direct way is to find how is the production Django app being ran. Look for bash scripts that start it, some `supervisor` entries etc

If you find how it starts, then you can pinpoint the environment it is launched in (e.g. which virtualenv)

### Find the virtualenv by searching for common files

Other than that you can use `find` or `locate` command to search for files we know to exist in a virtualenv like `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, `bin/activate` or `bin/python` etc

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If I were to recreate a new virtualenv, to enable it would I have to manually edit apache? Or is there an easier way of enabling the virtual environment as the host?

Comment: Apache would most likely be a _reverse proxy_ that forwards the requests to Django via some port (e.g. 8000), so if you use the same port you don't have to change it. Apache also serves static files for the app, so if the static files are where it looks for it, you don't have to do anything. Basically you are only replacing the virtualenv, and if you provide all the dependencies in it, you should be fine.

Comment: To confirm if I understand correctly, by "use the same port" do you mean use the same port on django? In other words, if i created a new environment, added all dependencies, then copied over the updated application files, as long as Django is on the same port, the host should direct the domain to the new environment?

Comment: If you get Django running on the port that Apache expects, you have solved the problem. Django cares about virtualenv, Apache doesn't. Apache in a typical Django just forwards the HTTP requests to Django and serves static files off the disk. Apache doesn't care/know about virtualenv.

Comment: Are you using `mod_wsgi` with Apache? Because this changes things

Comment: I would search in your Apache configs and you may find the path to your virtulaenv

Comment: The work on this server was done by an old contractor, so I am not sure how apache is set up (which is why I would rather avoid having to mess with it all together if possible). I am typically a JS developer so this is my first time deploying a Python/Django app, so I'm a bit unexperienced in this area. My only experience with virtual servers in the past was setting up virtual servers via administration panels and they typically gave public folders to work with. Never had to manually edit Apache before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103147/discussion-between-n-drosos-and-bakkal).

Answer (score 0):

Why not start checking what *processes are actually running*, and with what commandline, using `ps auxf` or something of the sort. Then you know if its nginx+uwsgi or django-devserver or what, and maybe even see the virtualenv path, if it's being launched very manually. Then, look at the config file of the server you find.

Alternatively, look around, using `netstat -taupen`, for example, which processes are listening to which ports. Makes even more sense, if there's a reverse proxy like nginx or whatever running, and you know that it's proxying to.

The requirements.txt I'd ignore completely. You'll get the same, but correct information from the virtualenv once you activate it and run `pip freeze`. The file's superfluous at best, and misleading at worst.

Btw, if this old contractor compiled and installed a custom Python, (s)he might not even have used a virtualenv, while still avoiding the system libraries and PYTHONPATH. Unlikely, but possible.